# Wordpress loop uses unmodified posts array, why?

Tags: posts, wp-query, loop

I have this code in a Wordpress template:

```
$prepost      = $post;
$normal_args  = array(
    // here goes the args
);
$normal_query = new WP_Query( $normal_args );

echo 'BEFORE: ' . count($normal_query->posts);
wpse_210493_apply_advertising_position( $normal_query->posts );
echo 'AFTER: ' . count($normal_query->posts);

if ( $normal_query->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $normal_query->have_posts() ) {
        $normal_query->the_post();

        // do something here
    }
}
```

The output for `echo` commands is:

```
BEFORE: 25
AFTER: 23
```

Which is right since in the function `wpse_210493_apply_advertising_position()` I am removing those two but problem here is that `$normal_query->have_posts()` use the original `$normal_query->posts` and not the modified by the function and that cause two empty values at end of array causing this ugly result:

[image]

This is the function `wpse_210493_apply_advertising_position()`:

```
function wpse_210493_apply_advertising_position( &$posts, $return = false ) {
    $ad_posts = array();
    $content_posts = array();

    // Seperate $posts into "Ads" and "Content" arrays based on whether or not they have 'rw_adversiting_position' meta-data
    foreach ( $posts as $post ) {
        $position      = intval( get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'rw_adversiting_position', true ) );
        $post_date     = $post->post_date;
        $post_modified = $post->post_modified;

        if ( ! empty( $position ) ) {
            if( isset( $ad_posts[ $position ] ) ) {
                if ( $post_date > $ad_posts[ $position ]->post_date || $post_modified > $ad_posts[ $position ]->post_modified ) {
                    $ad_posts[ $position ] = $post;
                }
            } else {
                $ad_posts[ $position ] = $post;
            }
        } else {
            $content_posts[] = $post;
        }
    }

    // Sort the ads from smallest position index to greatest such that re-insertion properly factors in all ads
    ksort( $ad_posts );

    // Add the ads back into the content at their specified positions
    foreach ( $ad_posts as $position => $ad ) {
        array_splice( $content_posts, $position, 0, array( $ad ) );
    }

    // If $return is true, return the resulting array. Otherwise replace the original $posts array with it.
    if ( $return ) {
        return $content_posts;
    } else {
        $posts = $content_posts;
    }
}
```

Can any give me some advice around this? I am getting crazy and don't found a way to get this fixed

Comment: What is `wpse_210493_apply_advertising_position` doing?

Comment: I am closing this as a duplicate of your question from a couple of days ago.  This looks like you are still working on the same problem.

Comment: I was just about to post an answer :)

Comment: @s_ha_dum, from where I see it, this is a different question. I cannot post the answer to this question to the previous question. Besides, my answer would have contained an explanation on why it's not good to directly modify the `posts` property of a WP_Query. Well, I guess I won't answer it than...

Comment: From my perspective, the question is "why doesn't the code form question 210493 not work correctly?"  That makes this the same problem. And I see no reason why you can't answer the other question with  "don't modify the `$posts` property directly, do XYZ instead. I was thinking about doing that myself.

Comment: @s_ha_dum this is not a dupe of my question from days ago, that question was related to change/pre-proccesing the array by moving element internal mostly, this one refer to another different problem since is related to template post function call so I don't know why you say is a dupe I just want to no hick-jack the other post and open a new one for this purpose, you tell me if is wrong

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu I posted the function at main post, the function is working good I think the problem is on the template side when I try to use the modified `$normal_query->posts`

Comment: You shouldn't modify the `posts` property of a WP_Query, Reynier. Specifically because you are only modding it and not every other property of that query. You can solve your problem using a `foreach` and setting `setup_postdata()`. `foreach ($normal_query->posts as $post) : setup_postdata($post);`. Don't forget to run `wp_reset_postada()` after it.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu can you post and example of that?

Comment: No, I cannot. The question is closed. @s_ha_dum: the answer in the initial question has created the problem this question addresses. The two questions are referring the same problem, but they are subsequent. I would like to address this question, not the initial one.

Comment: Ok, let's hope @s_ha_dum remove the duplicate tag so you can answer

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu can you post your answer on the other post? I think our friend will not unmark post so you wont be able to answer. Take a look to update 4 on that post